# Why does '@' in add_definitions() make CMake incredibly slow?

Tags: cmake

When I add a preprocessor definition with an @ in it to my CMake script, Configure takes 10 times as long.

```
add_definitions(-DEMAIL="foo\@bar.com")
```

Any insights or solutions on this?

(I'm using CMake-Gui on Windows for Visual C++ 2013.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until CMake 3.1, there was an undocumented feature in CMake: in a CMake file, `@var@` would expand a variable named `var`, similarly to what `${var}` does. This probably had to do with the workings of `configure_file()`. CMake 3.1 removed this misfeature (`@`-expansion remained for configured files only). See the relevant section of [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/policy/CMP0053.html) for more info.

I believe there are some points in CMake C++ code where a fast direct-use path or a slow parse-and-expand path is selected based on an early check for special characters in a string. The presence of `@` would indeed trigger the slow path looking for variable expansions etc.

If you have the option, test with CMake 3.1 to see whether that is the cause of the slowdown.

If that doesn't help, or requiring CMake 3.1 is not an option for you, you can work around this by putting the "offending" macro into a header file and including that in your C++ code. If the expansion of the macro needs to depend on CMake variables, you can use `configure_file()` to create the header file.

Comment: Thank you, upgrading to CMake 3.1.1 fixed my issue. I can also acknowledge, that configure_file() does still expand the @...@ syntax just like before, because I make use of this feature.